# ASP.Net Core MVC cs0120 an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, exception, attributes

I am doing and Asp.Net Core MVC Application.

I have the Controller

```
 private readonly IActivityLogging _activityLogging;

 public HomeController(IActivityLogging activityLogging)
 {
     _activityLogging = activityLogging;
 }
```

Activity Logging is a class that Log errors

I have my Method that has a Try Catch, and I have en Attribute to handle exceptions
Here is my method

```
[ClientWebError(_isPartial:false, _activityLogging)]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Menu()
 {
   try
   {
   ...
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      await _activityLogging.LogError(Request, ex, ActivityLoggingUtil.TYPE_UNHANDLED_ERROR.Value);
   }
}
```

My Attribute is like this

```
public class ClientWebErrorAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly bool isPartial ;
        private readonly IActivityLogging activityLogging;
        public ClientWebErrorAttribute(bool _isPartial, IActivityLogging  _activityLogging)
        {
            isPartial = _isPartial;
            _activityLogging = _activityLogging;
        }
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
   ....
            if(!isPartial)
            { 
                var result = new ViewResult()
                {
                    ViewName  = errorViewName,
                    ViewData = viewData
                };
                context.Result = result;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = new PartialViewResult()
                {
                    ViewName = errorViewName,
                    ViewData = viewData
                };
                context.Result = result;
            }
            
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
```

I am handling the Log in the Catch in the Method.

Now I need to implement it in the Attribute Method, So I need to pass `_activityLogging` as parameter.

But I have the error  `cs0120 an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property _activityLogging`

I can not defined class `ClientWebErrorAttribute` as static
Is there a way to pass it as parameter? or I have to define `_activityLogging` inside  `ClientWebErrorAttribute` class

Thanks

Comment: use `context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IActivityLogging>` to resolve the dependency within the attribute.

Comment: HI, Where I am suppose to add this?
If I add it inside void OnException function returns an error
  IActivityLogging _activityLogging = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IActivityLogging>;
"Can not convert method group GetService to non-delegate type IActivityLogging"
Thanks

Comment: sorry, seems there is a typo.. missing paranthesis. `IActivityLogging _activityLogging = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IActivityLogging>();`